# Use of subtotal by ignoring the column header

Tags: excel, subtotal

I am trying to use subtotal to calculate the totals for a set of columns. The position of the rows can change for different scenarios. Since the position of the rows are fixed, I am unable to set a range. At present, the subtoal always includes the column header when calculating the total. Is there a way where in I can ignore the column header while calculating the subtotal for a particular column.

Update:
I have 2 tables in the excel sheet. Depending on the number of rows from the first table, the rows from the second table are shited down. I am trying to calculate the subtotal for the second table. Since the position of the second table is not fixed, I can not use the cell position to calculate the total.

Right now i am calculating the total as "=SUBTOTAL(3,XDO_?NUMBER?)" in the template, where xdo_?number is the defined name used for the column.  Since the position is not fixed, its inlcuding the header value too there by increasing the total calculation by 1. 
I do not know how to exclude the header value based on the column name. I cannot give the header position since its not fixed and it keeps changing.  The header name of that column is Number so I was wondering if there is way I could calculate totals by ignoring based on the column header name.

TIA

Comment: You need to be much more specific. Describe the specific structure of your data using a simple example, show what calculation you're trying to do, and what the problem is with what you've tried

Comment: What stops you from excluding the header row from the formula...

Comment: Updated the question with more explanation

Comment: Are you using excel tables?

Comment: As the subtotal applied is `COUNTA` header is always counted, just subtract 1 (i.e. =-1+SUBTOTAL(3,XDO_?NUMBER?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the subtotal applied is COUNTA header is always counted, just subtract 1
use this formula"

`=-1+SUBTOTAL(3,XDO_?NUMBER?)`

Comment: If the first table doesn't change, then it would subtract 1 in the wrong way. So I was wondering if there is away to subtract based the column header

Comment: Please explain why. Isn't your header always included? Isn't your header always a label? Would you post a picture of your tables? and you still have not answer: Are these Excel tables?